# Is the time between to these two times in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want to be able to find out if the time/date now is between 10am and 5pm on a Monday, in Actionscript 3.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) class, I'm sure there are many variations of this:

```
var now:Date = new Date();

if (now.day == 1 && now.hours >= 10 && now.hours <= 17)
{
    // it's a monday and you're probably at work (between 10am - 5pm)
}
```